# Why does my accordion list keep closing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, hybrid-mobile-app

I've created a side menu that contains accordion list. When I load the page, the accordion list has one section open because it's coded to be active on page load. However if I attempt to open another section... it opens the section but then closes straight away. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**List code:**

```
<ion-content class="has-header" id="accordian"scroll="false" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <h3><span class="icon-dashboard"></span>Group 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="card in cards"><a href="#">{{ card.title }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-tasks"></span>Group 2</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="card in cards"><a href="#">{{ card.title }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-calendar"></span>Group 3</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="card in cards"><a href="#">{{ card.title }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait until the execution of the `slideUp` function is completed ([by default the duration is 400ms](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/#slideUp-duration-easing-complete)) before you test if the next element is visible or not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
      var $elemH3 = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
          if(!$elemH3.next().is(":visible"))
          {
              $elemH3.next().slideDown();
          }
      }, 401);

  })
})
```

You can use some CSS to do this easily see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/nx2LkoLd/
You hide all sections but not the active one :

css code

```
li.active ul {
    display:block;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

The js and html code still the same.

Hope it's clear and will help you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Default position of accordion is collapsed... put this on the begining of your `$(document).ready` to expand it.

```
$('#accordian').collapse({toggle: true});
```

***EDIT:***

In your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordian').collapse({toggle: true});

});
```

Or... if you want your accordion expands independent of the `ready` event you can put this line anywhere in your js file (except inside another `function`):

```
$(function () { $('#accordian').collapse({toggle: true}); });
```

*Both will work, but I'm not sure if your own functions are working, so be careful. I'm sorry, no time to test. ;)*

Comment: Can you show me using my JS example becasue I have tried this and it breaks it altogther?